# How to make Highcharts understand "Year-Category" in CSV file?

Tags: csv, highcharts

I would have said that it worked before. Now, I have updated meanwhile to latest Highcharts version. And, no idea why, it suddenly wants absolutely to display the first "column" of my CSV file. It looks like this:

```
,Switzerland,Europe,Global
1980,0.02854,0.01931,0.00547
1981,0.02898,0.01931,0.00549
```

Highcharts ("my code") wants to display this ""-column. And if I change it to "Years", or "Categories", it's all the same. I don't have three, but four entries in the legend.

The Highcharts-code looks like this:

```
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line)
    {
        var items = line.split(',');

        // header line containes series name
        if (lineNo === 0)
        {
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item)
            {
                if (item!='')
                {
                    if(item == 'Switzerland')
                    {
                        options.series.push(
                        {
                            name:item,
                            lineWidth: 5, 
                            data:[]
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        options.series.push(
                        {
                            name:item,
                            data:[]
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        ....
```

I tried to change the line

```
  if (item!='')
```

to something like

```
  if ((item!='') && (item!=' '))
```

or

```
  if ((item!='') && (item!='Years'))
```

(when I added "Years" in the first place of the CSV file), but I only get than error messages...

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth, here is how it works now:

```
    $.get('data.csv', function(data)
    {
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line)
        {
            var items = line.split(',');

            // header line containes series name
            if (lineNo === 0)
            {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item)
                {
                    if (itemNo > 0)
                    {
                        if(item == 'Switzerland')
                        {
                            options.series.push(
                            {
                                name:item,
                                lineWidth: 5, 
                                data:[]
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            options.series.push(
                            {
                                name:item,
                                data:[]
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
            else
            {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item)
                {
                    if(itemNo == 0)
                    {
                        options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                    }
                    else if (item == "null")
                    {
                        options.series[itemNo-1].data.push(null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        options.series[itemNo-1].data.push(parseFloat(item));
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //console.log(options.series);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found similar example from the past and the problem is only with index, which is used during push points to series.
Parser:

```
 var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    zoomType:'xy'
                },
                xAxis:{
                    categories:[],
                    tickInterval:10,
                    tickmarkPlacement:'on'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Oviedo hoy'
                },
                series: []
            };

$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
                // Split the lines
                var lines = data.split('\n');
                    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                        var items = line.split(',');

                        // header line containes series name
                        if (lineNo === 0) {

                            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                                if(item!='')
                                {
                                        options.series.push({
                                            name:item,
                                            data:[]
                                        });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                        else {
                            console.log(options.series);
                            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {

                                if(itemNo == 0)
                                    options.xAxis.categories.push(item)
                                else
                                    options.series[itemNo-1].data.push(parseFloat(item));

                            });
                        }
                    });

                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, the only difference I see is the "itemNo-1". Besides that it doesn't help, I think the problem lies in the "header line contains series name" section. There, in the "$.each"-loop, there should be something like "if (itemNo == 0) {do nothing} elseif (item != '') { .... }". But for reasons I don't understand, this stops any computing in that part.

Comment: So which values are incorrect? I used itemNo-1 because, when you parse  and have if(itemNo == 0) then you put value to categories. It is right, but when you have i.e itemNo == 1 then you need to use itemNo-1, because series are numbered from 0, not from 0. So as a result if you didn't have itemNo-1 then you would have one empty serie.